# Querying for MongoDB object by objectid

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my sample object in mlab

```
{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "58cf4c03c1e0371864b27906"
        },
        "patient": {
            "$oid": "58cf4bfbc1e0371864b27905"
        },
        "appointments": [],
        "__v": 0
 }
```

I want to find it by using the $oid of the "patient" but i'm having trouble bc the console keeps returning null. This is my code:

```
 Data.find({patient: ObjectId(req.params.patientID)}, function(err, PatientData)
             {
                if (err)
                  { throw err; }
                else
                 {  
                   res.send(PatientData);
                 }

             });
```

Comment: I think it should be `{'patient.$oid': ObjectId(req.params.patientID)}`

Comment: No luck. It's still returning '[]'

Comment: Try `{'patient.oid': ObjectId(req.params.patientID)}`

Comment: The "$oid" is extended JSON showing that the _id value has the type ObjectID(...) (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#data_oid). The query should be filtering on "_id".

Answer (score 1):

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;   

Data.find({"patient.$oid": new ObjectID(req.params.patientID)}, function(err, PatientData)
```